# Java jar not reading files from the jar, only external folders?

Tags: java, jar, external

When ever I make a JAR, the JAR won't read the folder inside it, only a folder in the folder the JAR is it. OK, that wasn't very descriptive. So here is a photo I edited to support.[image]

I hope you get the idea now. So how would I fix this? I already have res and stats part of the build path in eclipse, now what?

Code I use to read the resources:

`Image player;
player = new ImageIcon("res/player.png").getImage();`

Comment: Please show the code you're using to load the resource.

Comment: Send code, no photos...

Comment: Unzip the Jar and make sure "res" is included within in.  Make sure you are loading the resources with `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsInputStream`

Comment: I edited it to show that @thst

Answer (score 5):

When using `ImageIcon` and passing it a `String`, it expects that the parameter refers to a `File`.

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29)

> Creates an ImageIcon from the specified file. ... The specified String
>   can be a file name or a file path

Files and "resources" are different things.

Instead, try using something more like...

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/player.png"));
```

Assuming that `res/player.png` resides within the jar in side the `res` directory.

Depending on the relationship to the class trying to load the resource and the resource's location, you may need to use

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/player.png"));
```

instead...

**Updated**

Some recommendations, as EJP has pointed, you should be prepared for the possibility that the resource won't be found.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/res/player.png");
ImageIcon img = null;
if (url != null) {
    img = new ImageIcon(url);
}
// Deal with null result...
```

And you should be using `ImageIO.read` to read images.  Apart from the fact that it supports more (and can support more into the future) image formats, it loads the image before returning and throws an `IOException` if the image can't be read...

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/res/player.png");
ImageIcon icon = null;
if (url != null) {
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
        icon = new ImageIcon(img);
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        // handle the exception...
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// Deal with null result...
```

Comment: And make sure that the getResource() result isn't null.